# Minimal Dominating Vector from a set of N-dimensional vectors in prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to write a program that constructs a minimal dominating vector for a set of N-Dimensional vectors. A dominating vector for a set S of vectors is defined as a vector whose ith component is greater than or equal to the ith component of every vector in S, with i ranging over all dimensions of the vectors. The dimension N must be taken as input from the user.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there an algorithm or pseudocode you have that you are having trouble implementing in Prolog?

Comment: It can be very easily implemented in C or C# .

Comment: Problem lies in implementing it in Prolog (using  P#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prolog doesn't have vectors. You can use lists, or structs of arity N.
In second case of course N must be less than the max arity allowed (SWI-Prolog has unlimited length...)

If you use lists, this code should do. I assume N is implicit from list length.

```
'minimal dominating vector'([V|Vs], Min) :-
  'minimal dominating vector'(Vs, V, Min).

'minimal dominating vector'([], M, M).
'minimal dominating vector'([V|Vs], MinSoFar, Min) :-
   maplist(min, V, MinSoFar, Updated),
   'minimal dominating vector'(Vs, Updated, Min).

min(X, Y, M) :- X < Y -> M = X ; M = Y.
```

test:

```
?- 'minimal dominating vector'(["abc","aab","uaa"],M),format('~s',[M]).
aaa
M = [97, 97, 97].
```

If your Prolog doesn't have maplist/4 (I can't remember this detail of P#) then replace `maplist(min, V, MinSoFar, Updated),` with `minvect(V, MinSoFar, Updated),`, and add this definition

```
minvect([], [], []).
minvect([N|Ns], [M|Ms], [R|Rs]) :- min(N,M,R), !, minvect(Ns,Ms,Rs).
```

**note, OT** when I tried P# some year ago, I found it very slow, and memory ungry. If you have big arrays, then you're better to use LINQ

Comment: I am getting this error: Session Terminated by Exception
Symbol conversion failed

Comment: Code is successfully compiled, really good implementation...there is some problem with test input..

Comment: Is there  clean way to convert this code to take integer vector

Comment: Do you mean in C# side or Prolog? Prolog lists are untyped, you can pass whatever is comparable by operator <.

Comment: No not C#.. some problem with format in P# .. I am getting : Session Terminated by Exception Symbol conversion failed

Comment: I used strings to show the code running, but these "string"s are really lists of integers...Simply pass them to top level predicate.

Comment: Any idea about why I am getting that exception .. which compiler did you use

Comment: Sorry, currently I don't have P# ready, if you are using Visual C# express the debugger should help to locate the problem. Or try to locate 'Symbol conversion failed' in P# source. Otherwise place some write in your source to find the failing point...

Comment: have been doing that from quiet a time now ...... Have to spend the night with P# ... Might trouble you tomorrow ... Thanks Once again..

Comment: Yes, P# it's a bit uncomfortable.

Comment: I did the code finally ... Not as good as the one provided in answer .. but a decent parallel implementation in P#

Comment: Thanks to @CapelliC, Without his answer I wouldn't even have dared to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Serial Implementation:

```
fnt(M,N) :-
    fnt2(M,N,0,[]).

fnt2(_,N,N,Ds) :-
    reverse(Ds,R),
    write(R).
fnt2(M,N,K,Ds) :-
    column(M,K,Col),
    max_list(Col,H),
    K2 is K+1,
    fnt2(M,N,K2,[H|Ds]).


row(M, N, Row) :-
    nth(N, M, Row).

column(M, N, Col) :-
    transpose(M, MT),
    row(MT, N, Col).

symmetrical(M) :-
    transpose(M, M).

transpose([[]|_], []) :- !.
transpose([[I|Is]|Rs], [Col|MT]) :-
    first_column([[I|Is]|Rs], Col, [Is|NRs]),
    transpose([Is|NRs], MT).

first_column([], [], []).
first_column([[]|_], [], []).
first_column([[I|Is]|Rs], [I|Col], [Is|Rest]) :-
    first_column(Rs, Col, Rest).

nth(0,[X|_],X).
            nth(N,[_|T],R):- M is N-1,nth(M,T,R).

max_list([H], H).
max_list([H|T], M2) :- 
  max_list(T, M),
  M2 is max(H, M).
```

Parallel Implementation (Minor Tweaks)

```
fnt(M,N) :-
    fnt2(M,N,0,[]).

fnt2(_,N,N,Ds) :-
    reverse(Ds,R),
    write(R).
fnt2(M,N,K,Ds) :-
    column(M,K,Col),
    max_list(Col,H),
    K2 is K+1,
    fork(fnt2(M,N,K2,[H|Ds])).


row(M, N, Row) :-
    nth(N, M, Row).

column(M, N, Col) :-
    transpose(M, MT),
    row(MT, N, Col).

symmetrical(M) :-
    transpose(M, M).

transpose([[]|_], []) :- !.
transpose([[I|Is]|Rs], [Col|MT]) :-
    first_column([[I|Is]|Rs], Col, [Is|NRs]),
    transpose([Is|NRs], MT).

first_column([], [], []).
first_column([[]|_], [], []).
first_column([[I|Is]|Rs], [I|Col], [Is|Rest]) :-
    first_column(Rs, Col, Rest).

nth(0,[X|_],X).
            nth(N,[_|T],R):- M is N-1,nth(M,T,R).

max_list([H], H).
max_list([H|T], M2) :- 
  max_list(T, M),
  M2 is max(H, M).

reverse(A,R) :- reverse(A,[],R).
reverse([X|Y],Z,W) :- reverse(Y,[X|Z],W).
reverse([],X,X).
```

Test:

```
time(fnt([[1,2,3,56],[14,5,6,43],[7,8,9,22]],4)).
```

Comment: Thanks to @CapelliC, Without his answer I wouldn't even have dared to proceed